# Refreshing Dialog of QLabel in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

I am testing the updating of Qlabel. I basically have question displaying in random order, but the old text of the label still displays and combines with the new text. I am not sure how to clear it out between 'OK' clicks.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import random

class GameDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()

        lblWBS = QLabel("lblWBS")
        lblDialog = QLabel("lblDialog")
        btnOK = QPushButton("OK")
        layout.addWidget(btnOK, 5, 1)

        def randomOptions():
            rdmOpt = [2,3,4]
            random.shuffle(rdmOpt)

            optGreen = QRadioButton()
            optYellow = QRadioButton()
            optRed = QRadioButton()
            lblGreen = QLabel("Green")
            lblYellow = QLabel("Yellow")
            lblRed = QLabel("Red")

            layout.addWidget(lblWBS, 0, 1)
            layout.addWidget(lblDialog, 1, 1)
            layout.addWidget(optGreen, rdmOpt[0], 0)
            layout.addWidget(lblGreen, rdmOpt[0], 1)
            layout.addWidget(optYellow, rdmOpt[1], 0)
            layout.addWidget(lblYellow, rdmOpt[1], 1)
            layout.addWidget(optRed, rdmOpt[2], 0)
            layout.addWidget(lblRed, rdmOpt[2], 1)


            self.setLayout(layout)
        randomOptions()
        btnOK.clicked.connect(randomOptions)

        self.setWindowTitle("PALCDMS")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
dialog = GameDialog()
dialog.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: It's worse than you think. You aren't appending text, you are actually creating a whole slew of new objects and adding them to your layout every time you click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to implement your idea you have errors, since you are creating new objects.

You should Save a list of the widgets that will change position and remove them with `removeWidget()` before making the changes, and then put them back in the layout.

```
class GameDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)

        lblWBS = QLabel("lblWBS")
        lblDialog = QLabel("lblDialog")
        btnOK = QPushButton("OK")
        layout.addWidget(btnOK, 5, 1)

        optGreen = QRadioButton()
        optYellow = QRadioButton()
        optRed = QRadioButton()
        lblGreen = QLabel("Green")
        lblYellow = QLabel("Yellow")
        lblRed = QLabel("Red")

        layout.addWidget(lblWBS, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(lblDialog, 1, 1)

        l = [optGreen, lblGreen, optYellow, lblYellow, optRed, lblRed]

        def randomOptions():

            for w in l:
                layout.removeWidget(w)

            rdmOpt = [2,3,4]
            random.shuffle(rdmOpt)

            for i in range(len(l)):
                layout.addWidget(l[i], rdmOpt[i//2], i % 2)

        randomOptions()
        btnOK.clicked.connect(randomOptions)
        self.setWindowTitle("PALCDMS")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was trying the removeWidget before, I think I just had it in the work place.